# winload.efi corrupted after windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-10, ssd

I have Windows 7 on a regular SSD. I added a PCI-E SSD to my system, and I installed Windows 10 on it.

When I attempted to boot to Windows 7, I received an error that winload.efi was damaged, and now I cannot boot into Windows 7.

[image: winload.efi]

I attempted to Repair it by using my Windows 7 Ultimate disk, but that too received an error that my version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows you are trying to repair.

[image: windows 7 disk repair fail]

I booted Ubuntu on USB, used gparted to format the PCI-E to raw, but now I realize that Windows 7 cannot see the disk.

I am thinking my only option may be to get a new SSD/HDD, and install a new copy of Windows 7 on the separate disk to overwrite the garbage Windows 10 put on the boot partition.

I don't want to lose the Windows 7 files if possible.

How can I restore the boot for Windows 7?

Comment: What exactly is a "regular " SSD?